# Folder action acts on files not specified in the workflow

Tags: macos, automator, folder-action

I just started using Automator for the first time. My folder action gets two Finder items: say 'foobar1.pdf' and 'foobar2.pdf' files, and copies them to another folder.

It works but there is a side-effect: also the auxiliary files with the same name but different filename extensions (.aux .nav .snm .toc and .out) were also copied.

To solve that I created another folder action to send 'foobar1.aux', 'foobar1.nav' and so on to the Trash. But to test it, I did not add 'foobar2.aux', 'foobar2.nav' and so on. The new script works—the files are send to the Trash but now there is a beneficial side-affect: the auxilary files for 'foobar2' are also deleted even if they were not included in the workflow.

Is there a logical explanation for this behavior? Any way to avoid the side-effects?

[image: copying files]

[image: cleaning the folder]

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of your Automator set up.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Will do. Just a second have to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Folder Action` ***workflow*** will give you every file when a change is detected in the specified folder, including ones you are not interested in.

Your problem is with `Get Specified Finder Items`. It just adds items to the list of files to process. It doesn't filter anything!

Use the `Filter Finder Items` action instead to filter the list returned by Finder. You can do it any number of fields/options including name, extension and type.

[image: Filter Finder Items Action]

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Perhaps you could help with a related minor question also? When I modify the files in the source folder - for the workflow above to work, I have to delete the old versions before saving the new versions. If I simply save the new files over the old ones, nothing happens. Anyway to trigger a change in the specified folder just saving by the new files?

Comment: According to Automator's own help documentation, a Folder Action is to be used to detect **new** files in a folder. So it doesn't appear to support detection of changes. :(  Having said that, you can apparently use launchd to detect files changes and there are [other ways as well](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=osx+detect+file+changed)...

Comment: Thanks again! Also another alternative would be an script with rsync but I sill have to figure out how it works. :-)